# Can't set color of returned sprite?

Tags: c++, sfml

So, I have some variables in my game :

This is all the tiles in my game / the map.

```
std::vector<Sprite*> tiles;
```

This is the sprite variable which I have in a custom Sprite class.

```
sf::Sprite* sprite;
```

And here are my functions :

in main :

gameScreen.GetSpriteByPosition(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window), view), &window)->setColor(sf::Color::Black);

(That gives me a exception thrown error, Access violation reading 0x000000B4)

And this is the getSpriteByPosition function :

```
sf::Sprite* GameScreen::GetSpriteByPosition(sf::Vector2f mousePos, sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    sf::FloatRect mouseBound(mousePos, sf::Vector2f(1, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++)
    {
        if (lastSprite == i)
        {
            tiles[i]->setColor(sf::Color::Black);
        }

        else if (tiles[i]->getGlobalBounds().intersects(mouseBound) && lastSprite != i)
        {
            tiles[lastSprite]->setColor(sf::Color::White);
            tiles[i]->setColor(sf::Color::White);


            std::cout << "Found tile, index : " << i << std::endl;
            lastSprite = i;
            return tiles[i]->getDrawable();
        }

    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

And here's my getDrawable() function :

```
sf::Sprite* Sprite::getDrawable()
{
    return sprite;
}
```

Comment: Do you get a right position when you call `window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window), view)`?

Comment: @Tarod Yes, the function I'm adding that parameter to automatically changes color on the tile it is over. (which is working)

Comment: @Tarod I might have to add the function in this code too, I'll do it as soon as school is over :3

Comment: You don't provide enough information: why do you start by talking about sprites and get/drawable, but you highlight the fact that your issue is on a call to a setColor? I don't see the relation between all of these.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I get the error when I try to used the "returned" variable from my getDrawable() function. If I we're to not use it, it would work fine. I'm gonna add some mroe code to my post right away.

Comment: As I suggested in a comment of another of your questions, you should probably try to use pointers for your `sf` objects instead of instances. Or you should make your objects non-copyable. This would prevent a lot of this kind of errors that you seem to get.

Comment: How is it off topic? I don't need anyone to solve this exact problem. I just want to know why I can't use the returned pointer. I've had this problem before and I have had to scrap the entire project because of it.

Comment: Your question is off topic (now) because it is a general programming issue.

Comment: `return sprite;` does not return a _pointer_ (marked with the `*`) (it doesn't return a _reference_ either (marked with the `&`)), it returns a temporary _copy_ of `sprite`. `return &tiles[i]->getDrawable();` returns the address (reference) of that copy, but in this case, this copy is deleted after the call. So `GetSpriteByPosition` returns a reference to something invalid (it has been deleted), resulting in the crash that you get.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I tried making it a pointer which resulted in the same error though.... :/ Added the pointer modification to the post.

Comment: This is getting complex, I would suggest you invite me to a chat :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt How do I use the chat? Never used it before :3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34995/discussion-between-alexandre-vaillancourt-and-biix).

Comment: In theory you should have received at least one invite :)

Answer (score 3):

While not necessarily at fault here, `GetSpriteByPosition` returns a pointer to a temporary returned by `getDrawable`. You may not return pointers or references to locals or temporaries, as they do not outlast the function they appear in.

As for your error, you can divine some information from the faulting address.
`0xB4` is almost zero, which usually means that it's a member access or array indexing with a null pointer. There are no valid objects down near zero in the address space. Look at your call stack in your debugger to see where/how incorrect data creeps in.

Comment: No sure what `conjured from offsetting to a member` means... Google translate didn't really help. Told me something about magicians which I'm sure is wrong. lol

Comment: I played around some with the breakpoint feature, I added a picture of where the game crashes to my post.